# enable https for docker based site

Tags: docker, http, docker-compose, https, dockerfile

I was given a task to convert a site from HTTP to HTTPS.  The project is running in ASP.NET with React, and it's Dockerised. Below is the `Dockerfile` code:

```sh
  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
  WORKDIR /app
  COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ /app
  ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "some.dll"]
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file contains:

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:
  timescaledb:
    image: timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "******"
    volumes:
     - silver_timescaledb_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "5"
silver_ui:
    image: dev.azurecr.io/silver/silver_ui:1.0.1
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    volumes:
     - /etc/silver:/etc/silver
     - /var/lib/silver/:/var/lib/silver/
     - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
     - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "5"
    restart: always
volumes:
  silver_timescaledb_data:
    external: true
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're running into?  What in the setup you show configures the TLS listener and certificates?

Comment: @David Maze, i was asked to enable https for a site where the site is running in a IP, The site developed in React with Asp.Net  and Kestrel as server.

Answer (score 0):

I provide you an official Microsoft article about what you are asking for: [Hosting ASP.NET Core images with Docker over HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Please include context beyond just a link, ideally sample code that demonstrates what's behind the link.  Link-only answers are routinely deleted.